I can’t start Ubuntu after restarting
Whenever I try to start Ubuntu it just goes to a loading screen and I can't do anything. I have tried almost every option on the boot menu and nothing happens. It's totally unresponsive.


Did you update your system or install any packages before this issue?
You should try to enter recovery mode and reinstall GDM using the bash terminal. Just select "advanced options" and select the first option that contains the  "(recovery mode)" text.
May this help: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/17e158d/ubuntu_2310_is_stuck_on_ok_started_gdmservice/

You've provided few specifics as to what you're using, which can somewhat limited what we can offer. Are you using Ubuntu Desktop? if so what release are you using?  What change(s) were made in the last session before this issue occurred (they usually result in these problems, though hardware faults cannot be predicted) etc.  Please be specific with details; can you login to text terminal and view system logs to look for error(s)?
